# "Track-to-screen"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context

Can someone please explain what "track-to-screen" means in the following context:

> Michelin to make PlayStation’s Gran Turismo experience even more gripping for gamers through an unrivaled excitement to **track-to-screen** experience.

Comment: It's talking about narrowing the gap between ***real-world race circuits / tracks*** and simulated onscreen "gamers" versions thereof (as in Grand Theft Auto, I suppose).

Comment: Note that your version of the text contains a since-corrected error. The cited text was syntactically invalid / incomprehensible until ***excitement*** was changed to ***exciting***. Google's indexes still claim to find the former word, but [here on the actual site](https://www.michelin.co.uk/partnership/gran-turismo) it's already been corrected.

Comment: Please cite the source of the text you provide.